# Get sql.Tx out of gorm.DB

Tags: go-gorm

I'm working on a app using gorm to deal with database access.

I'm considering using an existing package for this and the package needs a `sql.Tx` struct value.

After starting a gorm transaction, I can get the `sql.DB` out of the `gorm.DB` but didn't find a way to extract the `sql.Tx`.

How do I get the `sql.Tx` from a gorm transaction db struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an instance of `*gorm.DB` called `db`, you can attempt to convert `db.Statement.ConnPool` to `sql.Tx` as such:

```
var db *gorm.DB // Passed in or created elsewhere
if tx, ok := db.Statement.ConnPool.(*sql.Tx); ok {
  // `tx` is an instance of `*sql.Tx`.
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).